# Facebook image for website doesn't change

Tags: images, facebook, open-graph-protocol

I am quite new to these SEO and all SEO aspects of social media. I just haved changed title text, description and image URL for websites homepage, but when I try to share it on Facebook, I still get old image, title and description. Is there a delay time or am I missing something?

These are meta tags I have:

```
<title>#LAISVA_LT | Visos šeimos - vienodai svarbios!#LAISVA_LT | Visos šeimos – vienodai svarbios!</title>
<meta name="description" content="Laisva.lt - Už laisvę rinktis! Už laisvus žmones! Už laisvą visuomenę! Neleiskime valdžiai naikinti Lietuvos šeimų! - Ištark griežtą &quot;NE&quot; Konstitucijos 38 straipsnio pataisoms.">
<meta name="robots" content="noodp">
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:title" content="#LAISVA_LT | Visos šeimos - vienodai svarbios!">
<meta property="og:description" content="Laisva.lt - Už laisvę rinktis! Už laisvus žmones! Už laisvą visuomenę! Neleiskime valdžiai naikinti Lietuvos šeimų! - Ištark griežtą &quot;NE&quot; Konstitucijos 38 straipsnio pataisoms.">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.laisva.lt/">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="#LAISVA_LT">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.laisva.lt/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/cropped-cropped-visos-seimos-svarbios.jpg">
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Laisva.lt - Už laisvę rinktis! Už laisvus žmones! Už laisvą visuomenę! Neleiskime valdžiai naikinti Lietuvos šeimų! - Ištark griežtą &quot;NE&quot; Konstitucijos 38 straipsnio pataisoms.">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="#LAISVA_LT | Visos šeimos - vienodai svarbios!">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://www.laisva.lt/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/cropped-cropped-visos-seimos-svarbios.jpg">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="http://www.laisva.lt/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/cropped-ikonai-1-270x270.jpg">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Invalid Code, Disallow, No-Index, Local Cache or Facebook Cache**

This problem normally occurs with invalid code, Facebook Caching or content blocking using either `no-index` or `robots.txt`.

Now, your code is valid, and the Cache is being refreshed using Facebook Debugging Tools, so it must be the later (no-index, or robots).

**Local Cache**

Using header expires it is possible to locally cache assests, for example you can tell browsers and crawlers to cache the content for one week,  or even a year! now, if you are using an expire on `*.jpg` and you happen to replace a jpeg with the same file name, all browsers, and crawlers that have a cached version the file, will not receive the update. This can be overcome by using versioning on your filenames, for example:

- `example.jpg?version2`

Or if you would like to keep things simple... just use a filename, that way... no one will have a cached version of it.

**Facebook URL Cache**

Facebook does cache fetch requests, otherwise Facebook would waste a lot of their bandwidth, but more so because they would be flooding people's websites with requests, especially when things trend, and go viral.

You can manually check the cache by using [Facebook's Sharing Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/), see  [Stack Overflow - Facebook not clearing cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776567/facebook-open-graph-not-clearing-cache).

However, [using Facebook's Object Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/), the new cache looks correct:

> ```
> Time Scraped  2 seconds ago
> Response Code 200
> Fetched URL   http://www.laisva.lt/
> Canonical URL http://www.laisva.lt/ (811 likes, shares and comments More Info )
> Server IP 79.98.28.33
> ```

So, it looks like Facebook is using the last used image, that it was 'Allowed to Index', see below.

**Disallow / No-Index**

Since you are using WordPress your media uploads as you most likely know, are stored in `/wp-content/uploads/`.

*Now taking a look at your robots.txt you have:*

```
User-agent: *

Disallow: /wp-content/
Disallow: /wp-*
```

Those **disallow values** will block search engines, social media platforms and all pother platforms respect the disallow value, simply put... your telling Facebook not to index your images.

Also, it's not advisable to block `/wp-content/` period, because you should want Google to index your images, its another way people can visit your site.

Comment: You Sir, you are awesome!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you update the OG metadata, you should use the Facebook debugger to 'scrape' the updated URL's metadata. Remember that such data is 'indexed' and is not dynamically updated so, visit the debugging page [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/), enter your URL, hit 'Debug' and you will be taken to a page with the URL OG data. Find the button that says 'Scrape Again', hit it. You should see the change in the link preview if you followed well.